# Extjs: Creating a date object from a AJAX (M$) formatted string?

Tags: .net, ajax, parsing, datetime, extjs

I have an **ExtJS** *listview* with a *JsonStore* connected to a *.NET* webservice. One of my columns has the type `Date` which I want to populate from a .NET DateTime object.

```
{
    header: 'Date',                
    dateFormat: 'M$',
    type: 'date',
    tpl: '{myTime:date("j. M Y, G:i")}',
    dataIndex: 'myTime'
}
```

My result from the webservice is

> /Date(1313669548625)/

I am getting an `Invalid date` error and a quick test concurs:

```
var myTime = '/Date(1313669548625)/';
var dt = new Date(myTime);
```

**How can I serve/parse the DateTime object so that my *listview* can handle the result?**

I have interpreted the ExtJS [documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Date) as ExtJS has extended the builtin *Date* object with parsing of MS Ajax formatted DateTime objects (*M$*).

Answer (score 1):

I checked and the way to use it  is var dt = new Date(Date(1313669548625)) without the slashes and quotes